# How to send textarea who contains html using Jquery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinyeditor

I have made changes on my comments for add TinyEditor(WYSIWYG). to send data i use this jquery function

```
function AddComent(){
    var formulario="#send_coment";
    var url = "comentario.php";
    var destino="#leercomentarios";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(formulario).serialize(),
            success: function(data)
                {
                    $(destino).html(data);
                }
        });
    envio_comentario.reset();
    $("#iframe_a_limpiar").contents().find("body").html('');
}
```

I have tried to set json data datatype, and more option that i have read in other places, but my log say same concept, error 403, it only happens depending the html entities to send, if i use the editor only with one or none style it works.

By other side, i have tried to use tinyeditor on pure PHP HTML, and it works fine.

Anyone know where is the problem on my script.

---

(thanks to Quentin for all)
The problem is apache security mod, but i cant change it, i have seening a solution like this

```
function awesome() {
        elements = document.forms[0].elements;
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            switch(elements[i].name) {
                case "ads":
                case "shortDescription":
                case "template":
                case "questions":
                case "salary":
                case "jobs":
                    str = elements[i].value;
                    elements[i].value = str.replace(/</g,"#@!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return true;    
    }
```

How can i convert this code to do with only with textarea and send all form at same time?

Comment: sorry, i was writing to fast and i didn't see the epic fail, solved

Comment: u already did  `data: $(formulario).serialize(),` now whats the issue?

Comment: So your server responds with a 403 Forbidden error? What's that got to do with Javascript? Maybe you should detail what backend you're using.

Comment: I have read some about across domain security mod of apache that can be the problem, i have asked to my host.
but i cant stand why if i don't use styles it works

Comment: `mod_security` is going "It looks like someone is trying to submit HTML, that could be an XSS attack, ALERT! ALERT! Block the request! Block the request!".

Comment: what about this line `envio_comentario.reset();`. where did you define `envio_comentario`

Comment: i will´d change send_coment.reset(); it is only to clean inputs